# If null(AB) is a subset of null(A), does they have the same rank?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be a square matrices.
If every solution to $AB_x=0$ is also a solution to $A_x=0$

then $rank(AB)$ = $rank(A)$.

I'm not sure if the logic is good here :

$AB_x=0 \;\;and\;\;A_x=0\; \Leftrightarrow$ $AB_x-A_x=0\Leftrightarrow (AB-A)_x=0\Leftrightarrow$ $null(AB)=null(A)$

$\Leftrightarrow$ $rank(AB)=rank(a)$

I'm not sure if $(AB-A)_x=0\Leftrightarrow$ $null(AB)=null(A)$

Answer (score 2):

Your logic isn't good, and your notation is strange. As you correctly stated, $(A-AB)x=0$ (whatever you actually mean by that) is not enough to tell you that $A$ and $AB$ have the same null space

Here's what you should do instead: since $null(AB) \subset null(A)$, the rank nullity theorem tells you that $rank(A)\leq rank(AB)$.

However, it is generally true that for any matrices $A,B$, we have
$$
rank(A)\geq rank(AB)
$$
It follows that the ranks are equal.

Answer (score 2):

First observe that for every pair of matrices $A, B$ we have
$$rank (AB) \leq rank (A).$$
In fact 
$$rank (AB)=\dim(Im AB)=\dim (Im A_{|_{Im B}})\leq \dim (Im A)=rank (A).$$
On the other hand you have by hypothesis that
$$\ker (AB)\subseteq \ker(A).$$
In terms of dimensions it means
$$\dim (\ker AB)\leq \dim(\ker A),$$
and using the rank-nullity theorem you obtain
$$rank (AB)\geq rank (A),$$
hence the equality.